# How to Move Cloudflare Code From Header to Footer

Tags: cloudflare

I want to move following Cloudflare Code From Header to Footer

```
 <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
 try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=
 [{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths: cloudflare:"/cdn-  cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"802302a1741170af9cd1a6d4a353562a",petok:"65a55c     4936b5ba77732bd7e22d0cd0659f2a74da-1441275430- 1800",betok:"a306a4b060e1b1181a348e962189311608722454-1441275430- 120",zone:"caknowledge.in",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script  type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn- cgi/nexp/dok3v=e9627cd26a/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
 //]]>
  </script>
```

How to transfer this code from header to Footer

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unfortunately. That's where we have to place it for some optional features and apps to work.

Comment: I will see this code on may sites at footer then tell me how they can move this code in footer